# Can't see a data on datatable -DataTables warning: table id=tableData

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jakarta-ee, liferay

you may feel this question may be duplicate but none of those questions/solutions solved my problem,
1)I am using liferay 6.2 and serverResource method to fetch a data from a server and populating the data on data table plugin and making AUI ajax call from client.
2)I did alert the received GSON object, everything looks ok but I can't see data on the data table and the object is as per the docs but getting 404 error also on the console.

please refer the view.jsp and `function getFormDataFromServer()`

```
 <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.ResourceURL"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.*" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:resourceURL var="serveResource">
</portlet:resourceURL> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<head>
<!--links for this page -->
<%--<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"></link>
 <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<%-- <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --%>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<%-- <p>string from server=${initial_value}</p>  --%>
<button  class="btn btn-success btn-md"  id="getTableData" onclick="getFormDataFromServer()" >View Data</button>
<div id="tableDiv" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px"></div>
<div id="divForm">
<form id="taskform">
<div class="form-group">         
    <label>Enter the details of a task</label>

    <label for="task">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>task"/>

    <label for="desc">description:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>desc"/>

    <label for="user">User:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>user"/>

    <label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>startdate"/>

    <label for="enddate">End Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="<portlet:namespace/>enddate"/>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="sendFormData()" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#getTableData').click(getFormDataFromServer());

});


function sendFormData()
{
    //var formdata_jSonObj=JSON.stringify($('#taskform').serializeArray());

        AUI().use('aui-io-request',function(A)
                {
                    A.io.request('${serveResource}',
                    {
                        method:'post',
                        data:{'<portlet:namespace/>action':'formdata'},
                        form:{
                            id:'taskform'
                        },
                        on:{
                                success:function()
                                {
                                    alert(this.get('responseData'));
                                },

                                failure:function()
                                {
                                    alert("error in ajax");
                                    }

                            }   
                    });
                }
            );

    }

    function getFormDataFromServer()
    {
        console.log("-------------------------------getFormDataFromServer method is called");
        var table="<table id='tableData' class='display table table-striped table-border' style:'width:100%'>";
        table+="<thead><tr>";
        table+="<th>Id</th>";
        table+="<th>Name</th>";
        table+="<th>start date</th>";
        table+="<th>end date</th>";
        table+="<th>created on</th>";
        table+="<th>description</th>";
        table+="<th>created by</th>";
        table+="</tr></thead></table>";
        $('#tableDiv').html(table);
        AUI().use('aui-io-request',function(A){
            A.io.request('${serveResource}',
             {
                method:'get',
                data:{'<portlet:namespace/>action':'getTableData'},
                on:{
                        success:function()
                        {
                            //alert(this.get('responseData'));
                            var data=this.get('responseData');
                            console.log(data);
                          //var tempdata=[{"id":"1","name":"tiger nixon","start_date":"23/4/2019","end_date":"23/4/2019","created_on":"23/4/2019","description":"thippu","created_by":"23/4/2019"}];
                            var obj={"ajax":data,"columns":[{"data":"id"},{"data":"name"},{"data":"start_date"},{"data":"end_date"},{"data":"created_on"},{"data":"description"},{"data":"user"}]};
                            //var obj={"ajax":data,"columns":[{data:'id'},{data:'name'},{data:'start_date'},{data:'end_date'},{data:'created_on'},{data:'description'},{data:'user'}]};

                            $("#tableData").DataTable(obj);
                        },
                    failure:function()
                    {
                        alert("ajax failure: cannot able to get the data from server, something went wrong");
                    }
                   }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

how to resolve this error:DataTables warning: table id=tableData - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
this the docs : [link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)
I can't see what is wrong, help me to find it.

GSON object data:

```
[{"name":"testtaskname","description":"estst","user":"testuser","start_date":"2019-05-28","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":1},{"name":"testtaskname","description":"sdf","user":"sdf","start_date":"2019-05-28","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":2},{"name":"testtaskname","description":"fs","user":"testuser","start_date":"2019-05-28","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":3},{"name":"testtaskname","description":"df","user":"testuser","start_date":"2019-05-28","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":4},{"name":"add task","description":"updating the database","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-05-28","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":5},{"name":"creating the datatable","description":"using bootstrap\u0027s","user":"thippu","start_date":"0032-11-06","end_date":"0033-11-07","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":6},{"name":"task10","description":"check","user":"thippu","start_date":"0032-11-06","end_date":"0033-11-07","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":7},{"name":"task11","description":"check","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-05-27","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":8},{"name":"task12","description":"check","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-05-27","end_date":"2019-05-28","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":9},{"name":"task13","description":"check","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-03-13","end_date":"2019-05-17","created_on":"2019-05-28","id":10},{"name":"creating the datatable","description":"updating the database","user":"testuser","start_date":"2019-06-18","end_date":"2019-06-21","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":11},{"name":"abc task","description":"checking the servlet","user":"user","start_date":"2019-06-01","end_date":"2019-06-01","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":12},{"name":"task demo","description":"description of task is checking the code is reaching or not to server","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-06-01","end_date":"2019-06-01","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":13},{"name":"task demo2","description":"checking the action value","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-06-01","end_date":"2019-06-01","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":14},{"name":"task demo","description":"checking the data","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-06-01","end_date":"2019-06-01","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":15},{"name":"task demo","description":"ggj","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-06-01","end_date":"2019-06-01","created_on":"2019-06-01","id":16},{"name":"demo project","description":"description","user":"thippu","start_date":"2019-06-03","end_date":"2019-06-03","created_on":"2019-06-03","id":17}]
```

Comment: Are you getting the 404 for the resource that is supposed to return this JSON? Well then that’s the reason for your error right there, you got to fix the 404 …

Comment: @04FS , you can see the code, alert gave me the GSON data but if I inspect on the browser I can see 404( Not Found) on the console. Is there any code need to be changed on JS?

Comment: What I meant was, is this a 404 for the JSON resource you are trying to request here (if that 404ed, then it should not go into the success handler to begin with, so you should not get any alert either), or for something unrelated?

Comment: @04FS I am not sure from where but there is no 404 from the resource which returns GSON data.

Comment: please see this link: https://ibb.co/Xx70tqz

Comment: Well that is obviously the URL-encoded version of your JSON data. You somehow triggered the browser into treating this data as a _URL_ somewhere.

Comment: `var obj={"ajax":data,` - here is your mistake, the `ajax` option must be a _URL_ to request the data from, not the actual data.

Comment: @04FS can u show me the fix for this? I have data.

Comment: 404 error is disappeared now, but what is the fix for this?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194437/discussion-between-thippu-and-04fs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the some code to the jquery part and it worked fine,
below is the solution:
In `function getFormDataFromServer()`
on `success` method change to:

```
                        {

                            var tbldata=this.get('responseData');
                            tbldata=JSON.parse(tbldata);
                            console.log(tbldata);

                            var obj={"data":tbldata,"columns":[{"data":"id"},{"data":"name"},{"data":"start_date"},{"data":"end_date"},{"data":"created_on"},{"data":"description"},{"data":"user"}]};


                            $("#tableData").DataTable(obj);
                        },
```